# Displaying Text Link VB.Net 2003

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, visibility, .net-1.1

I'm using window base application (.NET Framework 1.1)

I have a problem on displaying Text Link on form. Sometimes the text link doesn't appear after Form Load. I'm sure that the text link visibility property was set into `TRUE` and no other code was called to set it into `FALSE`.

Can anyone else know why this happen?

Thank you

Comment: You mean _after_ form load, right? Of course it can't appear _during_ form load, as the windows message loop hasn't been able to process any paint messages yet to draw the control to the screen. The message loop won't be allowed to process messages until after the load event has finished.

Comment: yes after form load. the user can't see any text link on window. what's happening there?

Comment: And the code is? ... but I'd look at the position of the control (whether it's positioned in the visible area), whether it's been added to the form's controls collection, and whether there might be another control in front of it.